# Use two shapefiles in one Leaflet map in R

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-r

My query along with a minimal working example is already posted here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924514/using-data-from-2-shapefiles-with-leaflet-in-r?noredirect=1#comment84855712_48924514

I did not receive a reply on stackoverflow so I am posting again.

Basically I have a shapefile for a region and subregions in a country. I want to make a Leaflet map such that each time I hover over a point, I see the boundary of the REGION and  the name of the SUBREGION and REGION.

I am not able to do this in one leaflet map. I can do this in two separate maps.

Can someone help me?